Branch still pushing from old account
I needed to switch github accounts to push something to a company github account. I tried to change to my new username but constantly get rejected.
    remote: Permission to Company/project.git denied to oldUserName.
    fatal: unable to access 'https://company.com/Company/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Here is all the troubleshooting I've done:

gh auth logout/gh auth login. When I check the status, I'm apparently logged into the correct account but still can't push from it.
git config --global user.email "newemail@company.com"
Setting up an SSH key for my new User Name
git remote set-url https://github.com/userUserName/project. The url was gotten from git remote -v and the following error was gotten:

usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

    --[no-]push           manipulate push URLs
    --[no-]add            add URL
    --[no-]delete         delete URLs
    enter code here

I've read through plenty of stackoverflow questions and github tutorials but they all seem to be failing. I really appreciate any advice or help.

The username or account used in fetch/push is NOT user.name or user.email. Search for credential helper. The old account is most probably cached in a helper. You need to delete or update the cached one or disable the helper.

You are using HTTP url and not SSH, so setting an SSH key doesn't do anything. Your last command returns error because you omitted the remote name.

@ElpieKay Thanks; I unset the credential.helper globally and to this repo and am still getting this 403 error.

as you can see in the error message you get from git remote set-url : <newurl> should be the second parameter. <name> should be the name for that remote -- most probably: origin. So: git remote set-url  origin  https://github.com...

It looks like you have two separate questions here: 1. How to use a different user name to push to Github than the one you've been using. 2. How to change the URL for a remote. You should be able to find the answer to both of these with some google-foo. I think part of the problem is that you are trying to solve both of them at the same time. Instead, try to fix each one separately.

I set up another ssh key and deleted my old one.
